# My discord bot is unable to send messages

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

i'm new to StackOverflow and discord programming.
I don't speak english very well so forgive me for errors.

Back to the problem : my discord bot doesn't send me a reply when I send "ping". It should send me "pong".

Here is the code :

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: 3072});
const token = 'token'

client.once('ready', () => {
   console.log('Félicitations, votre bot Discord a été correctement initialisé !');
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.content === 'ping') {
        message.reply({
            content: 'pong',
        });
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Thanks for help, tips to improve my code or myself at programming are welcome.

Comment: Are you using `”token”` for execution? That won’t work.

Comment: Hello !
I'm not using 'token' for execution, I replaced my true token by this for evident purposes.
In facts, the bot launches succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable reading of messages in the discord developer portal? You need these instead of the intents (MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT) to read message content. You can do this here: https://discord.com/developers/applications